# Add current browser URL into HTML hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension.

I want to add the current URL into a HTML link, like the following example:

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="this-is-where-the-current-link-will-go">Search</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You can do it manually in a text editor I guess. But seriously, show the code, manifest.json, or at least tell us where is that code (content script, popup, background page script) and what is the actual problem.

Comment: Thank You..,.!, This is the popup.html.. what are the permssions that wan't to do this???

Comment: If it's inside extension popup that's displayed when you click the extension icon then you'll need chrome.tabs.query and "activeTab" permission: [How to fetch URL of current Tab in my chrome extention using javascript](//stackoverflow.com/a/18436323)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The snippet will throw an error, but window.location is what you are looking for]

Set an ID to your anchor tag. 
then do this:

```js
var link = document.getElementById("demo");
link.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + window.location;
```

```html
<a id="demo" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=**Current URL**">Search</a>
```

Comment: @ChathinduSL then you can choose my answer as solution right ?

Comment: you should try `link.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + window.locatoin;`

Comment: Try this in your code, the snippet will not be able to get the window url, because it is designed to parse the JS codes inside of this page

Comment: `window.locatoin` should be `window.location`. However, even with this changed it should not work for what the OP has described as the problem (in a Chrome extension `action_button` popup).

Comment: Sorry for the typo, OP wanted to google search whatever is in the urlbar. and that is what the answer does. OP has accepted that, he knows better what he needs for chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:document.location = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + document.URL">Search</a>
</body>
</html>
```